# Kerberos and DNS relation

Tags: authentication, dns, kerberos, spn, mit-kerberos

The Kerberos principals are usually defined as `role/host@REALM`. How is the host field used over here?

Does it enforces that only that particular host can get a Kerberos ticket whenever `kinit` is run?

- If yes, then it makes sense for proper DNS to be setup.
- If no, how is the hostname useful?

I created a principal with name `xyz/garbage@REALM` in the `kadmin.local` panel, downloaded the keytab and distributed it to a different host machine. I tried to do `kinit` using this keytab and it worked.

Is that the correct behavior? How do I check if my Kerberos is using DNS or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct and the host part is not tied to the physical host. You can roam with your keytab.

Consider that you can use different DNS zones outside of your realm names for load-balanced services sharing one `http/fancyhostname.company.io@AD.COMPANY.COM` in a keytab. In such a case `domain_realm` section is used or Kerberos Forest Search Order (KFSO) in Windows.

DNS comes into play to discover the Key Distribution Center (KDC) and make TXT lookups instead of `domain_realm` stuff (does not apply to Windows).